# Tips/Tricks for Initial Guess of the Joint Variables in Inverse Kinematics

Tags: inverse-kinematics

It seems like there should be a set of best practices or something to reduce the iterations of the Newton-Raphson method to the inverse kinematics. Does anyone have any tips or tricks for choosing an initial guess for the joint variables when calculating the inverse kinematics? Or any papers that review/discuss/theorize this?

Comment: Like any problem I suppose the ICs are always annoying...but correct me if I'm wrong...don't you have an initial starting point to begin with...? Or do mean for subsequent calculations for other trajectories

Comment: You have both an initial state of each joint, and also the desired transformation. The initial guess for the joint variables would be the starting joint angles closest to the desired transformation. As the Newton-Raphson is a method for nonlinear root-finding for the scalar _x_ and _θ_.

Comment: Is the transformation in joint or cartesian?